# Different vendor versions of Java for Build and Runtime

Tags: java, java-8

If I build using 1 vendor's jdk (say Oracle JDK) and use runtime from another vendor (say Open JRE), is it guaranteed everything should work fine?

From what I have seen I don't see much issue if you have compiled with one version and run on another version of Java - as long as the major version is same. Also I know that you could run Java code compiled with older version on newer major version of java.

Comment: All Java compilers (so long as they don't have errors) should emit valid Java bytecode, which should be interpretable by any JVMs of that target version or greater. Note that [some JVMs may have different features which don't exist in other JVMs](https://www.baeldung.com/oracle-jdk-vs-openjdk) but I expect it wont be an issue for you.

Comment: Yes it is guaranteed (modulo bugs, as usual) provided that you use a runtime whose version is at least the one used to build.